# Error initializing VNC client in Guacamole

Tags: ubuntu, vnc

I am trying to allow remote desktop connection to users on a LAN to a machine running Ubuntu 14.04.

I have setup [Guacamole](http://guac-dev.org/) (using [these instructions](http://guac-dev.org/doc/gug/installing-guacamole.html#idp98448)) and I am able to connect to the web-application, but when I launch the remote desktop connection. I get this error message:

```
Error initializing VNC client
```

Here is the `syslog`

```
syslog:May 18 16:32:07 robot-slave guacd[25568]: Protocol "vnc" selected
syslog:May 18 16:32:07 robot-slave guacd[25568]: ConnectClientToTcpAddr6: connect
syslog:May 18 16:32:07 robot-slave guacd[25568]: ConnectToTcpAddr: connect
syslog:May 18 16:32:07 robot-slave guacd[25568]: Unable to connect to VNC server
syslog:May 18 16:32:07 robot-slave guacd[25568]: Error instantiating client: UNKNOWN STATUS CODE:
```

Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah.

It's stating "Unable to connect to VNC server". Is a VNC server instance running on the remote machine? It looks like it's not getting an answer from a listening VNC server.